# How to compare Prop changes in Svelte 3

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Is there a mechanism in Svelte 3 for comparing prop changes inside a component before rendering? Similar to React [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

```html
<script>
 export let color;

  // Does anything like this exist in Svelte?

  beforeUpdate((changes) => {
     const same = changes.prev.color === changes.next.color
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want to execute a piece of code only when `color` changes, you can use the reactive declaration:

```html
<script>
  export let color;

  $: {
     console.log('color changed', color);
     // will only get called when the `color` changed.
  }
</script>
```

But if you want to execute that piece of code with both the current value and previous value, you can do the following:

```html
<script>
  export let color;
  let prevColor;

  $: {
     console.log('currentColor:', color, 'prevColor:', prevColor);
     prevColor = color;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: just wondering if setting `prevColor` can trigger another reactive statement where prevColor is used.

Comment: @thecodejack you mean this https://svelte.dev/repl/36d1988c4718405c9208cec2f02b6d2a?version=3.16.7 ?

Comment: kind of similar..but here was my exact concern..https://svelte.dev/repl/d4156f465dbe42a597309fb7af0799c0?version=3.16.7 ..with ReactJS, you can't do that in easy way but i can see Svelte handling it correct...Awesome

Answer (score 10):

I've actually written a package that uses Svelte Stores to give you a simple interface to reference as many previous values as you need.

[Svelte Previous](https://github.com/bryanmylee/svelte-previous).

```html
<script>
  export let color;
  const [currentColor, previousColor] = usePrevious(color);
  $: $currentColor = color;
</script>

{$previousColor} to {$currentColor}
```